# Custom policies in Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, checkin-policy

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and connect to TFS 2010. Unfortunately I can't check-in because of policy. I get an error:

Internal error in Custom Path Policy. Error loading the Custom Path Policy (The policy assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.CheckinPolicies.CustomPathPolicy, Version=10.0.0.0, ...' is not registered.).

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, after installing Power Tools for TFS11 I don't have this problem.

Comment: Silly question, but did you install it on the server or client machine? Did you get it from here: [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27832337-62ae-4b54-9b00-98bb4fb7041a) ? I have the same problem  with VS2012 & TFS 2010 but when I install the TFS 11 Power Tools (client machine) I get an message about the TFS Backup Plan not being installed on the App Tier.

Comment: I install it on client, I also got that message but when I use Custom installation instead of Typical, installation was successfully completed. Now I have only problems with StyleCop Check-in policy.

Comment: Just an update that it's now called: Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: and same for 2013... may want to edit this so it just says "install the appropriate Power Tools for TFS (2010, 11, 13, 15) because this issue is related to that suite of tools" or something.

Answer (score 1):

In Team Explorer, try right clicking `Team Members`, Personal Settings and tick "install downloaded custom components" and/or click the Download Now button

Comment: I was also facing the same issue with lots of Internal errors in Custom Path Policy. I just followed the same above instruction and It solved the issue. But remember we also need to restart the VS and "pending changes" tab to reflect the downloaded policies.